# How to put a file to hdfs with secondary group?

Tags: hadoop, permissions, hdfs

I have a local file

```
-rw-r--r--   1 me developers 102445154 Oct 22 10:02 file1.csv
```

which I'm attempting to put to hdfs:

```
/usr/bin/hdfs dfs -put ./file1.csv hdfs://000.00.00.00/user/me/
```

which works fine, but the group is wrong

```
-rw-r--r--   3 me me 102445154 2013-10-22 10:23 hdfs://000.00.00.00/user/file1.csv
```

How do I get the group `developers` to come with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [chgrp](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/file_system_shell.html#chgrp) option on the file.